# Using javascript, how to select clicked item from autocomplete list?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to do this with plain Javascript not jQuery. I have a script which makes an ajax call and returns a changing list of items, based on keyup event. So we may have a list like this after 3 characters ("eth") are entered in to the search box:

```
ethereum
ethereum-classic
ethos
ethlend
etherparty
etheroll
ethereum-blue
ethorse
ethbits
etheriya
ethereumcash
ethbet
ethereum-gold
ethereum-dark
ethereum-movie-venture
ethgas
etherdelta-token
ethereum-lite
```

Now I would like to select one item form the list by clicking it. The code so far is:

```
function loadDoc() {
        var string = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "";
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
       obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
             for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<div>" + obj[i].id + "</div>";
                        }
                        document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", "div", function(){
                        var item = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
                        //var item = this.getElementById("demo")[0].innerHTML;
               alert(item);
             });
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/search?string=" + string, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

Everything works fine except the lines

```
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", "div", function(){
                            var item = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
                            //var item = this.getElementById("demo")[0].innerHTML;
```

I have tried multiple variations of this and the best I have achieved is the click event capturing the whole list, I want the clicked item to be the only item returned. What is the correct way to achieve this with Javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe look at this : https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/ or other autocomplete libraries

Comment: thanks, from first look, appears to be full framework and uses angular or jquery. I would prefer to use vanilla javascript.

Comment: hmmm maybe this will do : http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/

Comment: I will work my way through the second you sent me, thank you. I will see if I can find there an example of "click" event which meets my needs. I don't want to use a full framework. All the same, thank you for your input I appreciate it.

Comment: @niceman its not actually necessary to use a full framework for this, the `addEventListener` is defined wrongly. you may take a look at my simple revised code posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define [`addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) wrongly, the callback function must be the second parameter. Then, you can use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to access the clicked item. Here is a sample code:

```html
<div id="demo">demo</div>

<script>
  //assume you get all items in this obj
  var obj = [{id:"ethereum"}, {id:"ethereum-classic"}, {id:"ethos"}, {id:"ethlend"}, {id:"etherparty"}] //...

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";

  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<div>" + obj[i].id + "</div>";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      var item = e.target; //event.target
      alert(item.innerText); //get text of selected item (eg "ethereum")
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: certainly will and thanks again. To add the final touch, to help other people: document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var item = e.target; //event.target
  var searchboxitem = item.innerText
  document.getElementById("searchbox").value = searchboxitem;
 });